# How to Get a Distinct Filtered QuerySet In Django Without Using the distinct Method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Below is my post model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                        related_name="post_votes", default=None, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, default=None, blank=True)
```

I want to filter posts which contain a certain query in their title, content or as the name of one of their tags. To do this I've tried:

```
query_set = Post.objects.filter(Q(content__icontains=query)|
                                        Q(tags__name__icontains=query)|
                                        Q(title__icontains=query))
```

But this often returns QuerySets with duplicate results. I have tried using the `distinct` method to solve this, but that results in incorrect ordering when I sort the posts later on by the number of votes they have:

```
query_set.annotate(vote_count=Count('votes')).order_by('-vote_count', '-datetime')
```

If anybody could help me I would be very grateful.

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicates originate from the fact that you *filter on related objects*. This means that Django will perform a query with a `JOIN` in it. You can of course perform a uniqness filter at the Django/Python level, but those are inefficient (well the ineffeciency is two-fold: first it will result in more data being transmitted from the database to the Django server, and furthermore Python does not handle large collections very well).

Furthermore the line:

```
query_set.annotate(vote_count=Count('votes')).order_by('-vote_count', '-datetime')
```

is basically a *no-op*, since `QuerySet`s are *immutable*, here you did *not* sort the `QuerySet` on votes, you constructed a *new* one that will do that, but you immediately throw it away, since you do nothing with the result.

You can *add* the annotation and ordering and thus obtain *distinct* results later on:

```
query_set = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(content__icontains=query)|
    Q(tags__name__icontains=query)|
    Q(title__icontains=query)
).annotate(
    vote_count=Count('votes', distinct=True)
).order_by('-vote_count', '-date_time').distinct()
```

The `distinct=True` on the `Count` is necessary, since, as said before, the query acts like a `JOIN`, and `JOIN`s can act like "multipliers" when counting things, since a row can occur *multiple* times.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Willem. Great explanation and your solution works perfectly.